# Перевод большого числа в шестнадцатиричную СС С++

Tags: c++

Есть программа, реализующая возведение в степень двух чисел, результат - большое десятичное число - хранится в векторе (последние 9 разрядов - в элементе 0, следующие 9 - в элементе 1 и т.д.). 
Результат необходимо **вывести на экран** в шестнадцатеричном виде. Подскажите как удобнее это реализовать.
Текст программы:

```cpp
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef vector<long long> largen;//объявление типа данных для хранения большого числа

const int base = 1000 * 1000 * 1000;

largen  multiply(largen a, largen b) {
    largen c(a.size() + b.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < a.size(); ++i)
        for (int j = 0, carry = 0; j < (int)b.size() || carry; ++j) {
            long long cur = c[i + j] + a[i] * 1ll * (j < (int)b.size() ? b[j] : 0) + carry;
            carry = (long long)(cur / base);
            c[i + j] = (long long)(cur % base);
        }
    while (c.size() > 1 && c.back() == 0)
        c.pop_back();
    return c;
}

largen strTolargen(string ps) {
    largen res;
    for (int i = (int)ps.length(); i > 0; i -= 9)
        if (i < 9)
            // atoi() конвертирует строку, на которую указывает параметр str, в величину типа int
            // .substr(a, n) возвращает подстроку [а, a+n). Если запрашиваемая подстрока выходит за границы конца строки, диапазон возвращаемой подстроки будет [a, size()).
            // .c_str() Возвращает указатель на массив символов с завершающим нулем, который содержит данные.
            // push_back() Добавление элемента в конец вектора
            res.push_back(atoi(ps.substr(0, i).c_str()));
        else
            res.push_back(atoi(ps.substr(i - 9, 9).c_str()));
    while (res.size() > 1 && res.back() == 0)// back() возвращает последний элемент
        res.pop_back();//pop_back() — удалить последний элемент
    return res;
}

//функция, реализующая бинарнае возведение в степень 
largen recbinpow(largen a, int n) {
    largen e;
    e.push_back(1);
    if (n == 0)
        return e;
    if (n % 2 == 1)
        return multiply(recbinpow(a, n - 1), a);
    else {
        largen b = recbinpow(a, n / 2);
        return multiply(b, b);
    }
}

int main() {

    string n;
    cout << "Enter n: ";
    cin >> n;
    int k;
    cout << "Enter k: ";
    cin >> k;
    largen a = strTolargen(n);
    largen result;
    //result = binpow(a, n);
    result = recbinpow(a, k);
    //result = multiply(a, a);
    //cout.setf(ios::showbase); // индикатор основания системы
    for (int i = result.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        cout << result[i];
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А в чём трудность поделить длинное число на 16 и взять остаток? Деление выполняется от старших элементов к младшим. Этот остаток будет младшей цифрой ответа. Затем делим ещё раз, и ещё, получая цифру за цифрой, пока число не закончится.

Comment: Если планируется вывод в десятичной системе - то миллиард, понятно, легче. Но если вы изначально планируете работу в 16-ричной системе - то лучше использовать другое значение base - если 2^32 сложно - ну, хотя бы 2^28 или 2^24 - тогда вывод в 16-ричной системе предельно прост.

Comment: Если последуете совету @Harry, то у меня есть старые видео по длинной арифметике именно в таком формате. Начало здесь: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ei-SpjitN4